# Fujitsu A514 notebook SSD runs on SATA II speeds even though SSD and motherboard supports SATA III

Tags: hard-drive, debian, ssd, motherboard, sata

The problem is as in the title, I am getting lower speeds. 
My laptop: [Fujitsu Lifebook A514](http://sp.ts.fujitsu.com/dmsp/Publications/public/ds-LIFEBOOK-A514.pdf)
My SSD: [Kingston UV300 120GB](http://www.kingston.com/en/ssd/v#suv300s37a)

There is not much in the BIOS, just an option to turn SATA on or off.

Here is a sample benchmark.

```
# sudo hdparm -t /dev/sda

/dev/sda:
Timing buffered disk reads: 810 MB in  3.00 seconds = 269.84 MB/sec
```

And dmesg shows a SATA port at 3Gbps

```
# dmesg | grep SATA
[    0.817444] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: AHCI 0001.0300 32 slots 2 ports 3 Gbps 0x3 impl SATA mode
[    0.818062] ata1: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xf071c000 port 0xf071c100 irq 42
[    0.818065] ata2: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xf071c000 port 0xf071c180 irq 42
[    1.137606] ata1: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[    1.137624] ata2: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
```

Now my question is, is there something inside the OS that can trigger the switch to SATA III? Or has Fujitsu sold me a laptop on false product specs? I didn't try contacting them, and neither did I try using Windows, but will it help? I am on Debian testing, kernel 4.3 and tried on Debian stable, with similar results.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Based on my researched.  The speeds you are getting are within he specification of that SSD.  `sata 3 0 gb` is the speed of the interface it has.    The device is to put it simply, bargain bin hence the reason its limited, so verify your using the current firmware for it.

Comment: If you convert the MegaBytes into MegaBits, you will see that you are getting well over 2 GigaBits.

Comment: Yes true that. Those are still SATA II speeds. I checked with my friend who has the exact same SSD. He's getting around 400MB/s, 3.2Gb/s. I wonder what's wrong with mine.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience most often the SATA cables/connectors were the reason for bad signal quality and slower UDMA modes. I had to put the HDD in my ASUS laptop in the second slot because it slowed down after 3 years of use - now it is fast enough again.

dmesg should state anything about UDMA### timeout and about switching to a slower mode. If there are no messages about timeouts (and "throttled" UDMA modes afterwards) your cables should be ok. You can try to enforce a specific mode on a specific (SATA-)port through providing an additional option to the kernel at boot.

Comment: My laptop has the SATA port directly plugged into the motherboard. There are no cables. I will just check again if I missed anything although I am pretty sure there aren't.

Comment: My laptop also has the SATA port plugged into the Motherboard directly. It has two of them. With "cables" I meant actual SATA cables and soldered SATA ports, sorry. If dmesg does not tell you anything about UDMA modes and timeout, your cables should be ok anyway. There's a kernel parameter to force a specific UDMA mode for a specific port, if you want to try that.

Comment: It does say something, I am not sure if it is just info or some error. http://pastebin.com/JNgxKXvb

Comment: Typical read speed of your SSD is 323 MB/s, max. 495 MB/s? If the UV300 is almost the same as the V300 you can be happy to get a read speed of more than 240 MB/s. http://ssd.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Samsung-840-Evo-120GB-vs-Kingston-SSDNow-V300-120GB/1886vs1892
It does not answer your qustion, but maybe you don't want to waste more time on this topic. It's strange that the driver says it's a SATA II/3 Gbps port...

Comment: Yes I agree. I think it is not fruitful to spend more time on this topic. Although I would still try to get in contact with someone from Fujitsu in future, right now I would like to thank you for taking the time to try to solve this thing. :-)